# Linux usernames /etc/passwd listing

Tags: linux, sorting, grep, etcpasswd

I want to print the longest and shortest username found in `/etc/passwd`. If I run the code below it works fine for the shortest (`head -1`), but doesn't run for (`sort -n |tail -1 | awk '{print $2}`). Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

grep -Eo '^([^:]+)' /etc/passwd | 
while read NAME
do
  echo ${#NAME} ${NAME}
done |
sort -n |head -1 | awk '{print $2}' 
sort -n |tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both the head and the tail from the same input, you may want something like `sed -e 1b -e '$!d'` after you sort the data to get the top and bottom lines using `sed`.

So your script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -Eo '^([^:]+)' /etc/passwd | 
while read NAME
do
  echo ${#NAME} ${NAME}
done |
sort -n |  sed -e 1b -e '$!d'
```

Alternatively, a shorter way:

```
cut -d":" -f1 /etc/passwd | awk '{ print length, $0 }' | sort -n | cut -d" " -f2- | sed -e 1b -e '$!d'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here the issue is:

Piping finishes with the first **sort -n |head -1 | awk '{print $2}'**  command. So, input to first command is provided through piping and output is obtained.

For the second command, no input is given. So, it waits for the input from STDIN which is the keyboard and you can feed the input through keyboard and press ctrl+D to obtain output.

Please run the code like below to get desired output:

```
#!/bin/bash

    grep -Eo '^([^:]+)' /etc/passwd | 
    while read NAME
    do
      echo ${#NAME} ${NAME}
    done |
    sort -n |head -1 | awk '{print $2}' 

    grep -Eo '^([^:]+)' /etc/passwd | 
    while read NAME
    do
      echo ${#NAME} ${NAME}
    done |
    sort -n |tail -1 | awk '{print $2}
```

'

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
$ awk -F: '
    NR==1 { min=max=$1 }
    length($1) > length(max) { max=$1 }
    length($1) < length(min) { min=$1 }
    END { print min ORS max }
' /etc/passwd
```

No explicit loops or pipelines or multiple commands required.

Comment: Somehow, you always have another gem up your sleeve. Good job Ed.

Comment: this is actually easier I believe. Thank you very much Ed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you only have two pipelines, when you really need one. So you have `grep | while read do ... done | sort | head | awk` and `sort | tail | awk`: the first `sort` has an input (i.e., the `while` loop) - the second `sort` doesn't. So the script is hanging because your second sort doesn't have an input: or rather it does, but it's STDIN.

There's various ways to resolve:

- save the output of the `while` loop to a temporary file and use that as an input to both `sort` commands
- repeat your while loop
- use awk to do both the head and tail

The first two involve iterating over the password file twice, which may be okay - depends what you're ultimately trying to do. But using a small awk script, this can give you both the first and last line by way of the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

While you already have good answers, you can also use POSIX shell to accomplish your goal without any pipe at all using the *parameter expansion* and *string length* provided by the shell itself (see: [POSIX shell specifiction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)). For example you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

sl=32;ll=0;sn=;ln=;         ## short len, long len, short name, long name
while read -r line; do      ## read each line
    u=${line%%:*}           ## get user
    len=${#u}               ## get length
    [ "$len" -lt "$sl" ] && { sl="$len"; sn="$u"; } ## if shorter, save len, name
    [ "$len" -gt "$ll" ] && { ll="$len"; ln="$u"; } ## if longer, save len, name
done </etc/passwd
printf "shortest (%2d): %s\nlongest  (%2d): %s\n" $sl "$sn" $ll "$ln"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh cketcpw.sh
shortest ( 2): at
longest  (17): systemd-bus-proxy
```

Using either pipe/head/tail/awk or the shell itself is fine. It's good to have alternatives.

(note: if you have multiple users of the same length, this just picks the first, you can use a temp file if you want to save all names and use `-le` and `-ge` for the comparison.)